# Dependency Property change triggered by collections but not single bindings

Tags: wpf, data-binding, navigation, prism, dependency-properties

My application has an Outlook-style menu on the left with the content showing on the right. I'm using Prism's navigation API. As a user navigates between menu items, the content that was last shown for a given menu item is displayed, so that the user can go back and forth between two areas to compare information. This involves having a main display region with a separate region for each "page" (i.e. UserControl for displaying content for the menu selection) nested within it.

Each page contains at least one instance of a particular control, and that control has a `DependencyProperty` with a `PropertyChangedCallback` handler. What I've noticed is that, when the page is navigated to, all the controls on the page that have collections bound to them trigger the control's `PropertyChangedCallback` handler (which is what I want) but none of the non-collection bindings do.

I can see that navigating to a page triggers the `NavigatedTo` event on the main (outer) region. I don't want the NavigatedTo event on the page-specific (inner) region to be triggered, so that's fine. But what I don't get is why *any* of the controls or bindings in the inner region would be notified of a change when it's the outer region getting the event.

Each collection binding is a `ListCollectionView` over `ObservableCollection`, and each collection item implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

My questions are these:

1. What event is each collection handling that my non-collections are not, triggering the dependency property change?
2. Why does navigating to the outer region affect the controls in the inner region? What event must the inner region be receiving?
3. How can/should I implement the non-collection bindings so that they have the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample I can just guess that your issue is not related to bindings or properties.

Most likely your problem is how your views instatiated. In one case when you switch views - you get old copy of a view from container (MEF? Unity?) and in another case new instance created and populated raising all those events.